# How to store small pieces of static data that is local for component?

Tags: reactjs

The following component displays some static data.

What is the idiomatic way to store static data that is local to components?

Is it fine as I have done to store the data in a module scoped variable called data?

Or should I do something else like perhaps creating a `./data.json` file that I import?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import SectionContainer, { 
    InnerSectionContainer, 
    FlexContainer, 
    FlexItem 
} from '../../ui/SectionContainer';
import ScaledImage from '../../ui/ScaledImage';
import { SectionHeading } from '../../ui/Headings';

const data = {
    title: 'Trusted by',
    imageSrcs: [
        require('../../../images/logo1.png'),
        require('../../../images/logo2.png'),
        require('../../../images/logo3.png')
    ]
};

const Logos = () => {

    const logoItems = data.imageSrcs.map((imageSrc, index) => {
        return (
            <FlexItem key={index}>
                <ScaledImage src={imageSrc} />
            </FlexItem>
        );
    });

    return (
        <SectionContainer>
            <InnerSectionContainer>
                <SectionHeading>
                    {data.title}
                </SectionHeading>
                <FlexContainer>
                    {logoItems}
                </FlexContainer>
            </InnerSectionContainer>
        </SectionContainer>
    );
};

export default Logos;
```

Comment: You don't need to turn it into actual json if you don't need to. If this data is going to be shared by multiple components, I would definitely move it into it's own file, and export constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have one or more `consts.js` file(s) on my codebase.

If it's static, needs to be on the frontend and is used to just *ONE* component, I just put it along with the component's own file.

If it's being used by a few components under the same component structure (say, a component that solves a particular problem, that has some sub-components, but the static information is not relevant to any other component outside of this scope), I'd create a `consts.js` file on that component tree.

And if it's something that's going to be used by everyone, say, a set of style colors that reactjs is going to need for some reason, just create a *global* `consts.js` file and import as needed.

---

That being said, it's just how I use it. You can create your own approach. Try, experiment, and use what seems to work best for you.

EDIT:

I just saw this part of your code:

```
const data = {
    title: 'Trusted by',
    imageSrcs: [
        require('../../../images/logo1.png'),
        require('../../../images/logo2.png'),
        require('../../../images/logo3.png')
    ]
};
```

This approach will work on a javascript file type like `consts.js`, like I mentioned above, but **NOT** on a `json` file, since you can't use `require` inside them (all data is static. there is no logic or imports).

Answer (score 1):

You should tend towards declaring static data as close as possible to where it will be used.  In other words, in the smallest scope that makes it visible to the code that needs it.

In javascript, then, if the data is needed:

- by one function, declare it in the function
- by one file, declare in the file
- by the methods of an object/class/component, declare as a static or instance property in the class
- by users of a class or object declaration, then also as a class static
- by several components of a package, then in `utils.js` (or similar) file
- by many classes/components, declare and export from a file in a "common" or "library" package

I wouldn't quibble about how you structured your example; it's perfectly fine.  Putting that data into its own .js file is unnecessary unless you know for sure it will be used by at least one other component.  Even then, if that other component also needs your `Logos` component, then exporting from where it is now would be fine.

When deciding about how to structure things, I think the first consideration should be: how can I make it easiest, for a future reader of my code, to figure out what I have done.